# Simple On-the-fly keystroke macro recorder?

Tags: keyboard, automator, automation

What I really want is a simple tool which has two keyboard shortcuts: The first starts/stops a keystroke recorder.  The second then plays back that recording.

I don't need anything else and though I'm open to more useful features, I don't want it to conflict with Alfred's brilliant multi-clipboard or Dash's brilliant code snippet macros.

Any ideas? Many thanks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's an expensive option (36$), but [Keyboard Maestro](http://www.keyboardmaestro.com/) can do this.

> Whether you are a power user or a grandparent (or both!), your time is
>   precious. So why waste it when Keyboard Maestro can help improve
>   almost every aspect of using your Mac. Even the simplest things, like
>   typing your email address, or going to Gmail or Facebook, launching
>   Pages, or duplicating a line, all take time and add frustration. Let
>   Keyboard Maestro help make your Mac life more pleasant and efficient.

Comment: Yeah I saw that but I wasn't clear on whether it would have the very simple hotkey based operation I was referring to.  I already have snippets with hotkeys. I just want one I can record and use on-the-fly for disposable bits of text I need to repeat in the short term.